# How or when do I get to use my skill points?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I have recently started playing Resident Evil 6 and have so far collected a few hundred skill points - although this is best guess as I can't work out how to see my total.

But how or when do I get to use these skill points? Based on game play so far and what I have seen, my best assumption would be at the end of each chapter. Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out you can purchase and select skills from the main menu. Go to Play Game > Campaign > Skill Settings.

Note: I know this wasn't here when I first started playing (although saying that the game pretty much starts itself on the first play) and I also only went to the main menu after completing my first chapter, so I don't know if this is a requirement or not.

Comment: I assume you can see the number of skill points you currently have from this page as well?

Comment: @JamesJiao: Yes, the "Skill Settings" page shows your current skill points that are available to spend